# treeLeft, treeRight and treeLevel value not updated in Symfony 2 Tree

Tags: symfony

My symfony 2 project require to assign users to a company hierachy. So I try to use tree of StofDoctrineExtension bundle for this project. Here is my Entity class for "category":

```
    <?php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=64)
     */
    private $title;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $treeLeft;
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $treeLevel;
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Gedmo\TreeRight
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $treeRight;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $root;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return ($this->title) ? $this->title : '单位'; 
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }



    /**
     * Get treeLeft
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getTreeLeft()
    {
        return $this->treeLeft;
    }



    /**
     * Get treeLevel
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getTreeLevel()
    {
        return $this->treeLevel;
    }



    /**
     * Get treeRight
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getTreeRight()
    {
        return $this->treeRight;
    }



    /**
     * Get root
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRoot()
    {
        return $this->root;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Category $parent
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setParent(\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Category $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }


    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addUser(\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove user
     *
     * @param \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function removeUser(\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

and my CategoryAdmin.php:

```
 ......
     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('title')
            ->add('parent', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Category', // tree class
                'query_builder' => function($er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->orderBy('c.treeLeft', 'ASC');
                },
                'required' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }
```

When I created an category entity, only parent and root value are correctly set, treeLeft, treeRight and treeLevel are zero. I check the sample in the document, it did mention someting about eventlistener. Should I add an eventlestener for this? and How?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I just used the folowing code to a frontend controller:`$food = new Category();
$food->setTitle('Food');

$fruits = new Category();
$fruits->setTitle('Fruits');
$fruits->setParent($food);

$vegetables = new Category();
$vegetables->setTitle('Vegetables');
$vegetables->setParent($food);

$carrots = new Category();
$carrots->setTitle('Carrots');
$carrots->setParent($vegetables);

$this->em->persist($food);
$this->em->persist($fruits);
$this->em->persist($vegetables);
$this->em->persist($carrots);
$this->em->flush();` it is working. So it seems related to sonataadmin but not tree. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I deleted all records and create new one, it works.